# Where are the generated JSP class files located?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am using Tomcat 7.1 and Eclipse Indigo to develop a Java Web Application.
I just want to ask if anybody knows where the JSP translated files (the java files) are stored? Its often i receive exceptions indicating the jsp java file line, but if i can not see the file it is more difficult to correct the bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Eclipse store generated servlet files for Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543868/where-does-eclipse-store-generated-servlet-files-for-tomcat)

Answer (score 13):

Doubleclick the Tomcat entry in *Servers* tab in Eclipse. You'll see something like this in *Server Locations* section:

[image]

If you haven't changed the server path and it thus defaults to Eclipse's workspace metadata, then the Tomcat's `/work` directory is not in Tomcat's own installation folder, but in the path as shown in the above screenshot.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you adhere the [JSP coding recommendations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) and you [avoid Java code in JSP altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202), then debugging will be so much easier, along with a lot of other advantages.

Comment: or those who cannot view the image, the path is .plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\<application>\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp

Answer (score 8):

The JSP translated files are stored (in Tomcat) in `/work/Catalina/localhost/[your_app_context]/org/apache/jsp/`.

Should check in other containers or web servers.

Comment: @tt0686 They'll be in the Eclipse directories somewhere, not in the TC work directory.

Comment: @tt0686 Are you using Eclipse-Tomcat integration?  If your Tomcat `work` directory is empty and you are using Eclipse-Tomcat integration it _could_ be placing the generated Java and  class files under Eclipse's build directory.

Comment: If you run jsp on server, they will be in work directory. In other cases, they will probably be in some other place.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the jsp compailed java classes in your workspace:
And the path is: workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\auctuus\org\apache\jsp\jsp\gbp\settings