# converting JSP to readable Java code

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I recently encounter some problems with compiling JSP to Servlets. The reason I want to convert JSP to servlets is that I want to do static analysis on the Java code.

I got the compiled Java files in Tomcat (i.e., I know where Tomcat keeps the Java files compiled from JSP), but the compiled files lost the actual Object names.

For example, it is what I saw from the Tomcat compiled servlet java file:

```
 private org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fdatatables_005ftable_0026_005ftheme_005frow_005fpaginate_005finfo_005fid_005fexport_005fdata_005fcssClass_005fcdn;
```

Is there any way that I can remove the Jasper abstraction and find the actual Object type?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: You can also find the generated .java files, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701699/where-are-the-generated-jsp-class-files-located). And then there are separate JSP compilers to precompile in the IDE; in Stack Overflow too.

Comment: `/work/Catalina/localhost/<AppName>/org/apache/jsp/`

Comment: JSP to servlets like bytecode to java, if you want servlets then write it by hand.

Comment: Still not quite understanding what you want. I would say that `TagHandlerPool` *is* the actual object type (it's part of Jasper's implementation of JSP), and `_005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fdatatables_005ftable_0026_005ftheme_005frow_005fpaginate_005finfo_005fid_005fexport_005fdata_005fcssClass_005fcdn` is the name of the variable. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: Or maybe you are trying to find the implementation class of the tag that is pooled in this object? In that case, I'd look for a downcast at the point where an instance is retrieved from the pool.

Comment: @erickson Sorry for the confusion. I want to see if it is possible to get the Object name/mapping of the implementation class. So, for example, I want to know if I can map `private org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool` to org.myPackage.User (a User object defined in the application).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jasper's name mangling, but what you have here is a reference to a pool of JSP tags. I think the tag in question  is `datatables:table`, with `theme`, `row`, `paginate`, etc. attributes set. Are you putting your `User` object into the request attributes? You should search the generated code for corresponding `getAttribute()` calls.