# How to find error occuring place in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm working with a Google app engine app and when i testing my app following error has occurred.

```
at org.apache.jsp.eCommersViews.media_jsp._jspService(media_jsp.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511).....
```

But i have no idea how to find the place that error happen in Media.jsp.
Can someone please tell me how to find the error.

Comment: Show us the code from `Media.jsp`, check the Line 92 in the jsp

Comment: Nope,Media.jsp is coverted to Media_jsp.java servlet file. so we can't find the error from line 92.

Comment: What is the actual error message? You've listed part of the stacktrace, but not the message!?

Comment: I need to know how to find the place. they only show the line no. of java file. not Jsp. i need to know the line that get error in media.jsp.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that there is no simple way to find out which line in the JSP is causing the exception. You can add print statements in to try and narrow the search down, ie: `System.err.println("pt1");` then check the logs to see which points were printed and which not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find generated java files depending on what you are using. 
If you are using Tomcat-Eclipse combination then check

[Where are the generated JSP class files located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701699/where-are-the-generated-jsp-class-files-located)

If on standalone Tomcat check:

<Tomcat installation dir>/work/Catalina/<localhost>/<app context>/org/apache/jsp/jsp

Comment: Thanks, But we use Jetty. How can do the same with jetty?