# Where are the class files of jsp files stored in netbeans 8.0

Tags: jsp, netbeans-8

I have two files in my sample web application: 'index.jsp, Jsp1.jsp'. When i run this web application where are the class files of these two jsp files stored in netbeans 8.0?

I searched for the class files in project folder but i couldn't find any.

Comment: look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701910/1066779)

Comment: @Rembo I wanted it to know in netbeans not eclipse.

Comment: which server/container you use to run your application?

Comment: check in `${apache-tomcat-install dir}\work\Catalina\localhost\${your application name}\org\apache\jsp`

Comment: inside work folder no files. Its empty!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late but it may help someone!!

If you are using `glassfish` server, find the generated sources under

`C:\glassfishv2.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp`

*Note: I am using `glassfish 2.1`. In your case you may be using different version.*

For tomcat server it is well answered at [Where are compiled JSP Java (*__jsp.java) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files)

For your reference go through the documentation to enable generate source if you do not see at https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/i-want-to-see-my-jsps-generated-servlet-source

Answer (score 0):

In my system i could see class files on  C:\Archie\Dell\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JspExamples\build\generated\classes.I saw this path on output tab of a netbeans (after running jsp program) in JspExamples (run) section inside the output tab as:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Archie\Dell\MyDocuments\NetBeansProjects\JspExamples\build\generated\classes