# Where can I find the source or the compiled file for jsps generated by Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

So every jsp is **translated** into a .java file and then compiled to a .class file, but where can I find this file?

I am using Tomcat 8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files

Comment: look at this link (bu linke bakabilirsin :) ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701699/where-are-the-generated-jsp-class-files-located

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeap, exactly that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

```
apache-tomcat\work\Catalina
```

folder and go through the directory hierarchy to find `.java` and `.class` files.