# Deployed web App path from Eclipse using Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse IDE and in the IDE i have integrated TOM cat server. I have made one simple Dynamic project having one JSP page. My question is where i will find the servlet which Tomcat generated from JSP. I want to know the Folder path. And when i am lookin at webapps folder in TOMCAT it is empty, so where eclipse deploy web  applications( folder path)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat configurations are given [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543868/where-does-eclipse-store-generated-servlet-files-for-tomcat) for temp directory path to check servlet storage